# Javascript code to recognize all possible combinations of winning

Tags: javascript, combinations, tic-tac-toe

I am working on making a tic-tac-toe game for the science fair and I need help for recognizing all possible ways of finding a win rather than writing all of them down with brute force.

The game mechanics were just started today and I just started learning javascript (about 5 days ago) so I might not be the best looking code and the most efficent one. Also take notice i'm not done yet as this code is not 100% finished but i'm just putting my code for anyone who would like to look as I only need the combinations for all the possible wins. If you would like to watch me and help me while I work I would gladly invite you to see my code on **Gitlab** (I know its not the most famous but its very nice).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                table,tr,td{
                    border-style:solid;
                    border-length:1px;
                }
            </style>
            <script>
                    var s1="s1";
                    var s2="s2";
                    var s3="s3";
                    var s4="s4";
                    var s5="s5";
                    var s6="s6";
                    var s7="s7";
                    var s8="s8";
                    var s9="s9";
                    var turn=0;
                function gotClicked(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9) {
                    if (!(id1="s1" || id2="s2" || id3="s3" || id4="s4" || id5="s5" || id6="s6" || id7="s7" || id8="s8" || id9="s9")) {
                        switch(x1 || x2 || x3 || x4 || x5 || x6 || x7 || x8 || x9) {
                            case x1:
                                var x1=NA1;
                                turn++;
                                if(turn=3) {
                                    if(s1=NA1 && s2=NA3 )
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p id="s1" onclick="document.getElementById('s1').innerHTML='x';var id1=x1;gotClicked();"><a href="#">N/A</a></p>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <p id="s2" onclick="document.getElementById('s2').innerHTML='x';var id2=x2;gotClicked();"><a href="#">N/A</a></p>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <p id="s3" onclick="document.getElementById('s3').innerHTML='x';var id3=x3;gotClicked();"><a href="#">N/A</a></p>
                    </td>
                <tr/>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p id="s4" onclick="document.getElementById('s4').innerHTML='x';var id4=x4;gotClicked();"><a href="#">N/A</a></p>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <p id="s5" onclick="document.getElementById('s5').innerHTML='x';var id5=x5;gotClicked();"><a href="#">N/A</a></p>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <p id="s6" onclick="document.getElementById('s6').innerHTML='x';var id6=x6;gotClicked();"><a href="#">N/A</a></p>
                    </td>
                <tr/>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p id="s7" onclick="document.getElementById('s7').innerHTML='x';var id7=x7;gotClicked();"><a href="#">N/A</a></p>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <p id="s8" onclick="document.getElementById('s8').innerHTML='x';var id8=x8;gotClicked();"><a href="#">N/A</a></p>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <p id="s9" onclick="document.getElementById('s9').innerHTML='x';var id9=x9;gotClicked();"><a href="#">N/A</a></p>
                    </td>
                <tr/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks to one contributor for showing my mistakes!

Comment: There are only seven possible ways that the game can be won, yes?

Comment: I just relized that, but though that may be true I don't want to write it all down with brute force. Thanks, appreciate the help. EDIT:There are 8

Comment: _"EDIT:There are 8"_ Yes, you are correct. Are you trying to determine if the game has been won?

Comment: Brute force as in me writing down all possible combinations rather than it identifying all possible combinations without me directly writing it. I am trying to determine if the game was won. Thanks for the replay.EDIT:Deleted the combinations of winning since you realized.

Comment: Note, `html` and `javascript` at Question contains syntax errors

Comment: Can you please specify, thanks, just started 5 days ago.

Comment: At `html`, missing `!` before `DOCTYPE` at `doctype` declaration; `/` should be at left of `tr` at `<tr/>`; unexpected token `var` at `function gotClicked(var)`

Comment: Thanks for the help, edited it on top. Could you by any chance answer "Javascript code that finds all the possible values without writing it in brute force". Thanks you have been a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- `border-length` is not valid CSS, it shoud be `border-width`
- You are not doing comparisons in this `if` statement, but assignments:

  ```
  if (!(id1="s1" ...
  ```

  Use triple equality signs ( `===` ) to perform (strict) string comparisons.
- Your code would greatly improve if you would use an array instead of 9 separate variables: it will result in less duplication of almost identical code. For example, use this as your representation of the board:

  ```
  var board = Array(9);
  ```

  ... and put a 0 or 1 in a particular array element when the corresponding square receives and 'X' or and 'O'. For instance:

  ```
  board[0] = 1
  ```
- With the array presentation you can list a winning configuration as a triplet of indices in that array. For instance, if the values at index 0, 1 and 2 are all 1, then player 1 ('O') has won. All such presentations can be listed as follows:

  ```
  var wins = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6]
  ];
  ```

  The check for a win would be a matter of checking `board` entries at these indices to see they contain all 1 or all 0 (see code in snippet below).
- It is better not to write JavaScript code in HTML `onclick` attributes. For one, it results again in duplication of code, but it is also harder to debug when errors happen. Overall, it is considered better to separate code (JavaScript) from layout (HTML).

  Remove the `onclick` attributes and use `addEventListener` method instead inside your script:

  ```
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td a'), function (link, i) {
      link.addEventListener('click', gotClicked.bind(null, link, i));
  });

  function gotClicked(link, i) {
      // From the `turn` value we can know who the current player is:  0 or 1.
      // We use the modulo operator to get the remainder when dividing by 2: 
      var player = turn % 2; // alternates between 0 and 1.
      // Use this 0 or 1 as index in the XO string and display it.
      // When player is 0 this gives 'X', when 1 it gives 'O':
      link.parentNode.textContent = 'XO'[player];
      // Also put the 0 or 1 in our array
      board[i] = player;
      // Player played, so now increment `turn`.
      turn++;
  }
  ```

  For this to work, you should move your script to the end of your document, just before the closing `</body>`. Or, if you prefer it at the top, then wrap the code in:

  ```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      // your code that needs access to the document elements comes here
  });
  ```
- The click event handler should prevent the click from initiating a navigation. For that you can use `e.preventDefault()`, but you must then also get that `e` argument in your function.

  function gotClicked(link, i, e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // ... etc.
  }
- Don't use `innerHTML` when you just want to put text. For that purpose `textContent` is more suited.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // *** Initialise board with "empty" cells -- we use -1 for that:
  var board = [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1];
  var wins = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6] ];
  var turn = 0;
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td a'), function (link, i) {
    link.addEventListener('click', gotClicked.bind(null, link, i));
  });

  function gotClicked(link, i, e) {
    // Prevent the click on the link to initiate a navigation
    e.preventDefault();
    // *** call function to perform move: will return true when game is over
    if (doMove(i, 'You won!')) return;
    // ***Let AI play a move.
    randomAi();
  }

  // ***Separate function to perform a particular move: can be used for 
  // both players
  function doMove(i, msg) {
    // *** Get td-element that corresponds to the given index
    var td = document.querySelectorAll('td')[i];
    // From the `turn` value we can know who the current player is:  0 or 1.
    // We use the modulo operator to get the remainder when dividing by 2: 
    var player = turn % 2;
    // Use this 0 or 1 as index in the XO string and display it.
    // When player is 0 this gives 'X', when 1 it gives 'O':
    td.textContent = 'XO'[player];
    // Also put the 0 or 1 in our array
    board[i] = player;
    // Player played, so now increment `turn`.
    turn++;
    // Now board has changed, check if there is a 3-in-a-row for this player,
    // *** and return it as the result of this function
    if (isWinFor(player)) {
        // *** Show appropriate message
        alert(msg);
        return true; // signify end of game
    }
    // *** Detect a draw
    if (turn == 9) {
        alert("It's a draw");
        return true; // signify end of game
    }
  }

  // *** Modified completely
  function randomAi() {
    // ***Pick random number among the free cells. Make sure it is integer.
    var randomPick = Math.floor(Math.random()*(9-turn));
    // ***Find out its position on the board
    for (var i in board) {
        if (board[i] !== -1) continue; // used cell -- skip it
        if (randomPick == 0) break; // found it
        randomPick--;
    }
    // ***Perform this AI move
    doMove(i, 'You lost');
  }

  function isWinFor(player) {
    // Player is 0 or 1.
    // Iterate over all the 8 potential wins
    for (var win of wins) {
      // `win` is a triplet of indices, which when they contain the player's value
      // constitute a winning position. Let's count how many of those three
      // have the player's value (0 or 1)
      var count = 0;
      for (var index of win) {
        // Is the value on the board the value that corresponds to the player?
        if (board[index] !== player) break; // don't bother looking further.
        count++;
      }
      // If we have a count of 3 here, it is a winning position.
      if (count == 3) {
        // Don't try other wins: one is enough :-)
        // ***Remove all hyperlinked cells -- no move should be played anymore
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td a'), function (link, i) {
          link.parentNode.innerHTML = ''; // remove link
        });
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table,tr,td{
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  text-align: center
}
/* ***Fix the size of the board */
td { width: 30px; height: 30px }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">N/A</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">N/A</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">N/A</a>
    </td>
  <tr/>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">N/A</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">N/A</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">N/A</a>
    </td>
  <tr/>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">N/A</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">N/A</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">N/A</a>
    </td>
  <tr/>
</table>
```

#### Explanation

In comments you asked about this piece of code:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td a'), function (link, i) {
    link.addEventListener('click', gotClicked.bind(null, link, i));
});
```

It looks for all `a` elements that are descendants of `td` elements with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelectorAll('td a')
```

As the returned list is not an array, I convert it to one for easier looping, using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
Array.from(  )
```

The above returns array that I want to visit each element of. There are many ways to do this, but here I chose `Array.from` and using the callback function that can be provided to it: that callback is called for each element in the first argument.

At each call the next array element is passed to it as first argument, and a sequence number (the array index) is passed to it as second argument:

```
function (link, i) {   }
```

Within the function I call [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on the element (an `a` element) to listen to the `click` event:

```
link.addEventListener('click',   );
```

This really does something similar as the `onclick` attribute. The second argument passed to it must be the function that will be called whenever there is a click on this particular `a` element. For that I reference your `gotClicked` function. But as I want to pass it some arguments I use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
gotClicked.bind(null, link, i)
```

The first argument of `bind` is whatever `this` should be inside `gotClicked`. As I don't care about that, I pass `null`. But I do care about the real arguments passed to `gotClicked`: `link` (the element clicked) and `i` (the index of that element). Note that `bind` does not call the function, it just creates a reference to the function already specifying what will be passed as arguments once it will get called.

Comment: Really appreciate the help and the advise. I will try to follow these rules when I take my programming career to the next level. Really thankful.

Comment: The advise you gave me is very useful, when I checked on my science fair it was much to simple. Thanks for opening my eyes, if you would like to check out the project I was originally assigned then here is the link (assuming i'm allowed to post links to else were):http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/Games_p014.shtml">Tic-Tac-Toe. Awkwardly most of my family lives in Belgium.

Comment: Ah yes, that project is going a step further: writing code that suggests a good move. It's a small world ;-)

Comment: Hello again, while looking through the code and all I noticed this code snipet:                                                 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td a')).forEach( function (link, i) {
    link.addEventListener('click', gotClicked.bind(null, link, i));
  });                                                                                                                  --------
Don't want to seem like a bother but can you tell how this works as I don't want to just use some code of yours without knowing how it works as I want to recreate what you have given me. Thanks!

Comment: I added some explanations to my answer.

Comment: Sorry for extending the talk, can you explain what 'link' and 'i' are in the document, does link stand for <a href="#"></a> in the table. Also I have many more questions, any way I can talk with me in gitlab or on email as I am fairly new to javascript. Sorry if I seem like a bother, there is no programming teacher in my school and I have alot of questions I can't find online. You can decline if you want.

Comment: The `link` variable is indeed the element clicked on (see last paragraph of my answer), which is the `a` element. The `i` is its sequential index, starting with 0. For more questions concerning this answer, go ahead in this comment section. After a while a link to a chat box will be presented.

Comment: I really don't get the two functions (isWinFor) and (gotClicked) and how they do some of the mechanics, I'm sorry I am pestering you. This might be the last one I ask. Sorry

Comment: How would I go about adding a list that would allow me to switch between AI for player 1 and human and vice versa. Don't create the AI, just show me how they would fit together without causing a syntax error or malfunction. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a new question, please create one. If you want, you can leave the link to it in a comment here, and I will be happy to have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry I can't create a question for this since it is specific to this question, what is the ' i ' itself. Also how is the ' i ' used in this code.

Comment: *i* is the value that `Array.from` provides as second argument to the callback provided to it. In the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) this callback is described as *mapFn*, and receives the same arguments as the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. So *i* is the seq. number of an element in the array-like object passed to `Array.from`, i.e. it is the sequence number of the `a` element in the DOM, ie. it is a number from 0 - 8, one for each cell.

Comment: Why does this code only work here and not anywhere else, also is this pure js.

Comment: It is pure JavaScript, although Internet Explorer does not support `Array.from`. But if it runs here for you, it should run elsewhere also. What exactly goes wrong for you? Do you have an error message in the console?

Comment: I don't know but the Ai i added wont work and your original code wont work with anything I try, here is the link: https://gitlab.com/SmailBarkouch/Tic-Tac-Toe-Science-Fair-Project/blob/proto/Website-Directory/Javascript-Branch/GameMec-RandomAI.js

Comment: You really should check the console, because it shows clearly that your code has a syntax error on the line `var openSquare[];`. Another error appears for `math.random()`, because it should be `Math` with an initial capital. Please debug your code using the console.

Comment: No, there is more. But really, did you check the console? There is also an issue with `link.parentNode.textContent='XO'[player];` within your AI section, because at that time `link` is not an element in the document anymore. You probably wanted to do something else. But hey, did you open the console? Did you see the error?

Comment: I thought that link.parentNode.textContent='XO'[player]; would check all the board values and renter the values. Also I didn't check the console because I don't have one in the computer I use. Gitlab doesn't provide a js console. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is your browser that should have a console. What browser do you use? Like I wrote `link` is not a reference to an anchor in your document, because the previous occurrence of that statement *destroys* the `a` element, and replaces it with an `X` or `O`, so if you reference `link` after that, it will point to something that is no longer in your document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129350/discussion-between-smail-barkouch-and-trincot).

Comment: Another issue (I added it to my answer): you need to prevent the click on a link to perform a navigation, which would reset your page after each click. I added a bullet point about this in my answer.

Comment: Could you check the edit I made because it should be working, I made it so the link variable will not be already defined by putting it with- Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td a'), function (link, i) { 
link.addEventListener('click', gotClicked.bind(null,link,i),randomAi(null,link,i)); 
});

Comment: The comments section is not really suitable for follow-up questions. Anyway, adding `randomAi(null,link,i)` in `addEventListener` like that makes no sense. It gets executed immediately (not when the event happens), and passes as third argument of `addEventListener`, which has a different purpose.

Comment: I can't create a question for 5 days because all my questions get down voted. I only have 5 days til I submit my code so my question and last question is what are all my bugs to make this function in time. I swear I really appreciate what you do because no teacher in my school could help me. I tried to search online for a person to check my "broken" code but I can't find anything. I just really need this to be over, so could you please tell me all the bugs to make this function.

Comment: OK, I updated the code in my answer to use a modified version of your `randomAi` function. I have not updated that text of my answer. It should be clear from the comments. I will now concentrate on other questions if you don't mind ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of all possible winning combinations; create an array to store number at clicked element `id`; attach `click` event to each `p` element within `for..of` loop; use `Array.prototype.some()`, `Array.prototype.every()`, `Array.prototype.indexOf()` to check if each element in array containing clicked element digit portion of `id` is within an array containing a set of possible winning combinations and element `.innerHTML` is equal to `"x"`; utilize `setTimeout()` to allow time for last `"x"` to be rendered, then reset `<p>` elements `.innerHTML` to `<a href='#'>N/A</a>`, set array containing clicked element digit portion of `id` to `0` `.length`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    tr,
    td {
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var winners = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [1, 5, 9],
        [3, 5, 7],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [3, 6, 9]
      ];
      var clicked = [];
      var p = document.querySelectorAll("table td p");
      for (el of p) {
        el.onclick = function() {
          if (this.innerHTML !== "x") {
            this.innerHTML = "x";
            clicked.push(+this.id.match(/\d/).pop());
          };
          var win = winners.some(function(winner) {
            return winner.every(function(n) {
              return clicked.indexOf(n) > -1 
                     && document.querySelector("[id$='" + n + "']")
                        .innerHTML === "x"
            })
          });
          setTimeout(function() {
            if (win) {
              alert("winner");
              clicked.length = 0;       
              for (el of p) {
                el.innerHTML = "<a href='#'>N/A</a>"
              }
            }
          }, 1000)
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="s1"><a href="#">N/A</a>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p id="s2"><a href="#">N/A</a>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p id="s3"><a href="#">N/A</a>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="s4"><a href="#">N/A</a>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p id="s5"><a href="#">N/A</a>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p id="s6"><a href="#">N/A</a>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="s7"><a href="#">N/A</a>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p id="s8"><a href="#">N/A</a>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p id="s9"><a href="#">N/A</a>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```