# Javascript event handler `this` binding inside closure not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, this, jquery-events

Probably a simple fix but I've been stuck working through this now for a couple days. I'm building a tic-tac-toe project and I would like to build a method inside my `user` object called `userClick()` that satisfies the following conditions:

- When the user *clicks* on a tictactoe tile:
- Change the HTML text inside that tile (`div`) to the user's `marker` (X or O);
- add a CSS class of `taken` to the tile;
- increase the user's score/move count by 1.

Here's the relevant Javascript/jQuery code I've tried to fiddle around with:
    var user = {
    score: 0,
    marker: "X",

```
userClick: function() {
  $('.box').onClick(function() {
    this.text(marker);
    this.addClass('taken');
    score += 1;
  });
};
```

My HTML has 9 divs arranged in a tictactoe grid and all divs have the class of `box`. My CSS file also has a class of `taken` that changes the background color of the div when clicked. However, when I click on any of the divs, nothing happens. I've tried making numerous tweaks to the function to get it to work, with no luck. I'm still rather inexperienced with closures, event handlers, and `this` binding so maybe someone with more experience can shed some light on this for me.

Thanks!

Edit: Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbLxps8o/) of the entire code base so far in case it helps. (Problematic method begins at line 74).

Comment: Is that jQuery? `.onClick` should be `.on('click', function() {` or `.click(function() {` and `$(this)` inside handler to use jQuery methods on the clicked element.

Comment: `this` is element  you use  `$(this)`

Comment: jQuery binds the scope to current element for you when you use `.click(...)` or `.on('click', ...)`.
Your own `.onClick()` function won't do that, so you would need to explicitly bind it to the scope you need. You can use `.bind` for that, or call it with `call()` or `apply()` (thats JS native functions, not jQ)

Answer (score 1):

It's not fully clear to me (much less the parser) what you expect "this" to be in your context.  Is it the jquery selected element you want?  Or is it the user object?

Given that you're trying to add a CSS class to it, I'll assume you want the clicked element.  Your handler assignment should then look like so:

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    var box = $(this); // refers to the clicked element
    box.text(marker);
    box.addClass('taken');
    score += 1;
  });
```

Comment: duh, sorry; I was just copying his bit and paying attention to the problem he said he was having, not checking all his code.  Fixed in an edit, thanks!.

Comment: So I changed my `this` references to `$(this)` and alternatively tried assigning `$(this)` to variable box and using `box.text(...)` and it still doesn't work. I'm wondering, since the anonymous function in the click handler is inside another anonymous function (the value assigned to the `userClick` property of my user object, is the method having trouble determining what `marker` and `score` are a reference to? And if so, what's a good fix for that?

Comment: @M.Layton are you using `click` / `on` or `onClick` in your code?

Comment: @YemSalat, I've tried all three versions -- none of them work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

this inside the handler stands for the DOM element, but both text and `addClass` belong to jQuery Object. So you need to use them like this.

```
$(this).text(marker)
```

Answer (score 1):

I put a fiddle up here for a pretty bare bones jQuery tic-tac-toe per your mention: https://jsfiddle.net/6ynyr7hx/

**HTML**

```
<div id="game_container">
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    var marker_count = 1;
    $('.box').click(function() {
        if (marker_count === 9) {
            $('#game_container').append('GAME OVER');
        }
        if (marker_count % 2 === 00) {
            marker = "X";
        } else {
            marker = "O";
        }
        $(this).text(marker).addClass("taken");
        //Increment the counter
        marker_count = marker_count + 1;
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#game_container {
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

*NOTE: I didn't bother clearing the floats as this was just a quickie...

```
  // PROBLEM METHOD
  userClick: function userClick(marker) { <--- You have to pass the marker
    marker = "x";  <- That should be the passed marker
    $(".box").click(function() {
      $(this).text(marker).addClass("taken");
      score += 1;
    });
  }
}
```

you will need to pass the marker states and scores back and forth on changing turns etc... This at least gets you a little closer to play with it. Also remove all the html head code including the js and then use the javascript panel cog wheel icon to include jquery x.x.x and set it to onDomready. Pay attention to the terminations I changed in the above code. There was a straggler in there that was causing the script to fail. And un-comment out your on ready userClick function in the fiddle.

Comment: Some of this code is actually very informative for features I haven't implemented yet. I'm confused about why you've put the entire function inside the $();, but I'm assuming it'll work the same as a value assigned to an object property. However, even when I change the relevant parts based on your suggestion it still doesn't work. Here's a jsFiddle link to all the code in case it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/cbLxps8o/

Answer (score 0):

Missing `}` following function at `userClick`; call `user.userClick()` within `game.initializeGame()`; substitute `user.marker` and `user.score` for `marker`, `score` within `.click()` function attached to `.box` selector.

```
  // Game functions
  initializeGame: function() {
    user.chooseMarker();
    computer.chooseMarker();
    user.setMarkerInUI();
    user.updateScore();
    computer.setMarkerInUI();
    computer.updateScore();
    user.userClick();
    $('#score strong').text(totalScore);
  }


  // PROBLEM METHOD
  userClick: function userClick() {
    $(".box").click(function() {
      console.log(this, user.marker)
      $(this).text(user.marker);
      $(this).addClass(".taken");
      user.score += 1;
    })
  }
```

A start plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/cAOj0Xa0rcNucM9lft1G?p=preview

Comment: Its not at all clear to me how this code helps answer my question. I'm not sure how I would define a data() method or attach it to one of my objects to perform the functionality you've suggested. It also doesn't address how I would alter the function as I've currently written it to add the user's marker (X or O) to the div or add the "taken" class to the div, which is the currently non-working functionality my question is asking about

Comment: @M.Layton You can use jQuery as an object to store each `.box` element as a "user" object. `.data()` can store an object `{score:0}` where `score` value is incremented at an event. The `className` `"taken"` is added to the element at `click` event of element. Not certain what you mean by "add the user's marker"? Are you asking how to build the entire tic-tac-toe game using `html`, `javascript`? Note, jsfiddle link did not appear at original Question?

Comment: @M.Layton Note, try using plnkr https://plnkr.co to link files to `html`; jsfiddle does not link `<script type="text/javascript" src="tictactoe.js"></script>` to `JAVSCRIPT` panel.

Comment: So at the beginning of the game, the user would choose whether they want to play as "X"s or "O"s, and that choice will be stored as a string in the Object property user.marker. When the user clicks on one of the tic-tac-toe tiles (written in HTML as <div class="box"></div>, the click event should trigger the text inside the clicked div to add that string stored in user.marker.

Comment: @M.Layton Have you considered including that description at actual Question? As the current Question is presented, appears issue is described as _"I'm still rather inexperienced with closures, event handlers, and this binding so maybe someone with more experience can shed some light on this for me."_ See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , also this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39947483/)

Comment: @M.Layton There is a missing `}` following `userClick` function. Also, `marker` and `score` within `userClick` should be `user.marker`, `user.score`. Call `user.userClick()` within `game.initializeGame()`. A start https://plnkr.co/edit/cAOj0Xa0rcNucM9lft1G?p=preview